# SqlServer Maintenance plan log file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hi all I have a SQLSERVER maintanence plan that run every night, for some reason it's stopped running, when I run it manually it throws an error and states "Execution failed. See the maintenance plan and sql server agent job history for log details" Ive looked in program files/.../log and there is very little information in there

my procedure is as follows

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files  
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup  
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name

SET @path = 'D:\backups\'  

SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb','emhf')  

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       SET @fileName = @path + @name +'.BAK'  
      BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName
```

is there a way to write what its doing at each and every stage to a file so I can then find out why its falling over

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this could be such a simple mistake, but you have a missing `END`

If you right click on the maintenance plan, and select view history, you will find more accurate error descriptions.

Comment: Yeah sorry the actual code does have an END in there. If I view the history the last entry was yesterday, when I try and execute it now it seems to say its already running. but it deosn't seem to be doing anything. Is there any way I can stop it?

Comment: sp_who2 should help identify the SPID for the process. You can then `KILL` that SPID

Comment: ok ive run sp_who2 but I cant seem to find the job in the list, am I right in thinking it would be running on the master db

Comment: Even then it should show up. Please check SQL Agent Job Activity monitor, to see if the job status shows "Executing". BTW, have you closed and deallocated the cursor?

Comment: How do I check if I have deallocated the cursor?

Comment: I've found the job in the "job activity monitor" and cancelled it however, its still sat there

Comment: Ive just executed it again and it seems to be running now thanks

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).